# Jmeter: How to view failure rate in spike test

Tags: jmeter

I am planning to perform spike test in Jmeter. I came across a performance metric - "failure rate" while reading through some blogs. Can somebody please help with how to monitor this metric. Which listener is to be used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend something like [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/) which plots [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) over time

[image: JMeter Plugins Response Codes Per Second]

You can use it along with i.e. [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) - this way you will be able to correlate increasing number of errors with increasing loads.

[image: JMeter Plugins Server Hits per Second]

You can install both graphs using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Additional Graphs]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri . Will try installing the plug in and run the test.